# Connection refused exception while running hadoop jar

Tags: java, hadoop

I am new to Hadoop . I have installed hadoop-1.2.1 in linux-mint on VMware Workstation and when I try to run a sample jar inside hadoop it shows the following error:

```
hduser@linux-mint ~/hadoop $ hadoop jar hadoop-examples-1.2.1.jar  pi 3 10

Number of Maps  = 3
Samples per Map = 10
14/09/05 17:40:19 INFO ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: localhost/127.0.0.1:54310. Already tried 0 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1 SECONDS)


14/09/05 17:40:20 INFO ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: localhost/127.0.0.1:54310. Already tried 1 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1 SECONDS)


14/09/05 17:40:21 INFO ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: localhost/127.0.0.1:54310. Already tried 2 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1 SECONDS)


14/09/05 17:40:22 INFO ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: localhost/127.0.0.1:54310. Already tried 3 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1 SECONDS)


14/09/05 17:40:23 INFO ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: localhost/127.0.0.1:54310. Already tried 4 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1 SECONDS)


14/09/05 17:40:24 INFO ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: localhost/127.0.0.1:54310. Already tried 5 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1 SECONDS)


14/09/05 17:40:25 INFO ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: localhost/127.0.0.1:54310. Already tried 6 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1 SECONDS)


14/09/05 17:40:26 INFO ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: localhost/127.0.0.1:54310. Already tried 7 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1 SECONDS)


14/09/05 17:40:27 INFO ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: localhost/127.0.0.1:54310. Already tried 8 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1 SECONDS)


14/09/05 17:40:28 INFO ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: localhost/127.0.0.1:54310. Already tried 9 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1 SECONDS)


java.lang.RuntimeException: java.net.ConnectException: Call to localhost/127.0.0.1:54310 failed on connection exception: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobConf.getWorkingDirectory(JobConf.java:567)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileInputFormat.setInputPaths(FileInputFormat.java:318)
    at org.apache.hadoop.examples.PiEstimator.estimate(PiEstimator.java:265)
    at org.apache.hadoop.examples.PiEstimator.run(PiEstimator.java:342)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:65)
    at org.apache.hadoop.examples.PiEstimator.main(PiEstimator.java:351)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ProgramDriver$ProgramDescription.invoke(ProgramDriver.java:68)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ProgramDriver.driver(ProgramDriver.java:139)
    at org.apache.hadoop.examples.ExampleDriver.main(ExampleDriver.java:64)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:160)
```

My Jps gives the following output:

```
3792 SecondaryNameNode

4001 Task Tracker

3865 Job Tracker

3678 Data Node

3581 Name Node

4045 Jps

</i>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. you can remove or disable localhost your hosts file, hosts path example "/etc/hosts"

maybe restart your computer.

2. change your hadoop conf properties localhost to ip address. And run hadoop again.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is you don't have enough memory for the job to start. How much ram does your VM have?

Comment: hi my ram is 1 GB. But somehow it got solved. I formated the namenode